# What is the best setting for tsconfig.json working with node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, commonjs

So far I have 2 files in "./src": `index.ts` and `setConfig.ts`.
Both import 'fs' and 'path' like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
```

... and that's what Typescript obviously doesn't like; when compiling it says:

```
src/index.ts:1:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fs'.

1 const fs = require('fs');
        ~~

  src/setConfig.ts:1:7
    1 const fs = require('fs');
            ~~
    'fs' was also declared here.

src/index.ts:2:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'path'.

2 const path = require('path');
        ~~~~

  src/setConfig.ts:2:7
    2 const path = require('path');
            ~~~~
    'path' was also declared here.

src/setConfig.ts:1:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fs'.

1 const fs = require('fs');
        ~~

  src/index.ts:1:7
    1 const fs = require('fs');
            ~~
    'fs' was also declared here.

src/setConfig.ts:2:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'path'.

2 const path = require('path');
        ~~~~

  src/index.ts:2:7
    2 const path = require('path');
            ~~~~
    'path' was also declared here.


Found 4 errors.
```

But when I leave it out in `setConfig.ts` node complains that it doesn't know 'fs'....

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "rootDir": "./src/", 
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

So, what else do I have to add or do to make my compiled JavaScript work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding exports in your `setConfig.ts` module should solve the problem.

```
// setConfig.ts
export default {
  // your exports
};
// Or
export function foo() {}
```

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you!
I used ```module.exports = foo() {}``` and ```const setConfig() = require("./setConfig")``` which worked in js before but obviously not here in ts anymore...